# How to change background color of active line in Visual Studio Find Results Window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I just switched to a [dark theme](http://www.nerdpad.com/visual-studio/visual-studio-2010-dark-expression-blend-color-theme) in Visual Studio and can't find the setting for changing the background color of the currently active line in the Find Results Window. The obvious place for this is in Tools-Options-Fonts and Colors-Find Results Window setting, but there isn't a choice for the active line. I also looked in the Visual Studio Color Theme Editor but didn't see anything relevant.

I posted a [screen shot here](http://www.galleryserverpro.com/images/_tmpFindResultsWindow.png). It shows how the line is unreadable as well as the choices available in Fonts and Colors dialog.

Anyone know how to change it?

Thanks,
Roger

Comment: What is the background color of 'Current list location'? Did you try matching it with that of Plain Text?

Comment: No visible changes when I tried your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the color of Plain Text to black and the background to gray. That made everything readable while still keeping the background pretty dark.

Ultimately the original question remains unanswered, but the workaround is fine.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have the Power Productivity Tools extension installed? If so, it's likely the Highlight Current Line extension causing the problem. For some reason the Find Results pane doesn't respect your selections in the Fonts and Colors dialog for the Current Line (extension) and Current Line Inactive (extension) settings.

The only way I've found to fix the issue is to turn that extension off. Tools->Options...->Productivity Power Tools->All Extensions->Highlight Current Line->Off. Of course, doing this removes the benefits of the extension in the code editor window. Seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) Extension which has the capability to highlight the line in which the cursor is currently postioned. You can change the highlight line color by going into Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Current Line(Extension)

Visual studio Productivity power tools also has many great functionalities. Check it out.

Answer (score -1):

Change the settings for `Current List Location`. That'll solve it.

[image]

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work for me. Don't know if a plugin like Resharper is interfering or what...

Comment: I have resharper and that SS is with ReSharper on. You can suspend ReSharper and check. You can also try disabling extensions that you think may be interfering and check. Also, your Theme extension could be interfering. See if they have any setting to override.